# Trouble to recognize external monitors at startup

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I don't consider myself a linux guru. I'm not sure about what information I need to provide. I will gladly update my question if you give me the instructions.

## Setup

**HP Spectre x360 - 13-4190nz** with **Ubuntu 18.10**

**Office**
  laptop resolution: 2560x1440
  second monitor: mini-display to hdmi, 2560x1440 *primary*
  third monitor: hdmi 2560x1440

**Home**
  laptop resolution: 2560x1440
  second monitor: mini-display to hdmi, 1920x1080 *primary*
  third monitor: hdmi 1920x1080

*Note: I'm not entirely sure if my setup at home is exactly correct. I won't be home before a few days.*

## Detail of the problem

Whenever it's at home nor at the office, once I pass the login screen, Ubuntu detects only one of my external monitors and the screen is "*unstable*". The screen starts and stops like it has a bad contact or is badly connected. Once I open the **Display Arrangement** and change something, it fixes until the next reboot.

## Information

**Graphic card**

```
▶ sudo lshw -class display
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:148 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**Drivers**

```
▶ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] [103c:81a1]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device [0000]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub [8086:9d35] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub [103c:81a1]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_ish_ipc
    Kernel modules: intel_ish_ipc
```

**xrandr config**

```
▶ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 7680 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   2560x1440     60.07*+  59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95    40.05  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected 2560x1440+5120+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**~/.config/monitors.xml**

```
▶ cat ~/.config/monitors.xml
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>4480</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-1</connector>
          <vendor>ACI</vendor>
          <product>VS278</product>
          <serial>H5LMQS008692</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>2560</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-2</connector>
          <vendor>ACI</vendor>
          <product>ASUS VK278</product>
          <serial>B7LMTF079618</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>eDP-1</connector>
          <vendor>LGD</vendor>
          <product>0x0000</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>2560</width>
          <height>1440</height>
          <rate>60.074672698974609</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>5120</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-1</connector>
          <vendor>SAM</vendor>
          <product>S27H85x</product>
          <serial>H1AK500000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>2560</width>
          <height>1440</height>
          <rate>59.950550079345703</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>2560</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-1</connector>
          <vendor>SAM</vendor>
          <product>S27H85x</product>
          <serial>H1AK500000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>2560</width>
          <height>1440</height>
          <rate>59.950550079345703</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>eDP-1</connector>
          <vendor>LGD</vendor>
          <product>0x0000</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>2560</width>
          <height>1440</height>
          <rate>60.074672698974609</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of `~/.config/monitors.xml` as well and then leave a comment @Fabby?

Comment: @Fabby I have updated with `monitors.xml`

Comment: Apparently Canonical updated the monitors.xml to Version 2, so I'm not really helpful here...

Comment: I think the problem is at home the second monitor is 1920x1080 and at work the second monitor is 2560x1440. Ubuntu is remembering the settings from last location and switching to new location is causing confusion. My instinct would be to setup two scripts: one for booting at home and one for booting at work. Haven't given it much thought though...

Comment: The problem seems to happens mostly at work with the **2560x1440** screens. Every morning I have the same routing: delete `~/.config/monitors.xml`, loggout, login and resetting the display parameters. However, at home the configuration seems more "stable" with my **1920x1080** screens. I would guess this is more like a graphic card related problem.

Comment: Apparently the problem as been fixed since 1 or 2 week. I have no idea how since I didn't try anything specific. I'm suspecting an update. So... well.. Hurray for me!! I wont make this comment as answer since I'm not even sure why its working.